# how to add key and turn dictonary key to value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary like this:

```
a = {"RAM": ["25GB", "256GB"], "Storage":  ["25GB"]}
```

and is there any possible way to make dictionary like this?

```
wanted_dict = [{"title":"RAM", "items":["25GB", "256GB"]}, {"title":"Storage", "items":["25GB"]}]
```

i tried to do with for loop but with no result.
any advices?

Comment: Your result is actually a list, you can achieve this using the following syntax: `wanted_dict = [{"title": key, "items": value} for key, value in a.items()]`. Where `a` is the name of your dictionary.

Comment: Show your loop and its result.

Comment: [mre] for for loop is missing , what does "with no results" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = {"RAM": ["25GB", "256GB"], "Storage":  ["25GB"]}
list_a = [{'title': key, 'items': values} for key, values in a.items()]
```

Comment: can I ask why you like Crabby Fish's answer more?

Comment: your answer was good too, but i saw crabbys answer first and thats why i accepted that.

Comment: i personally do like using list comprehensions too. so thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand you want to convert the value of `a` to the value of `wanted_dict` without hard-coding it. If so, here's the code:

```py
a = {"RAM": ["25GB", "256GB"], "Storage":  ["25GB"]}
b = []

for key in a:
    entry = {"title": key, "items": a[key]}
    b.append(entry)

print(b)
```

So then you could do:

```py
a = b
```